# Wordpress - call to url via custom field in backoffice

Tags: php, json, wordpress, google-maps

I have this problem:

I want to create an input field in the backoffice for my custom post, for which I already use ACF.

I would like to call to the Google Maps API once the input field, which would be an address, has been filled (and eventually a button close to it, pressed) - which would then launch the call to the API and return the gmaps json which I would parse in order to get just the lat+long elements.

Would there be a good soul wanting to put me on the way? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in all it was the matter of :

- creating a custom meta field,
- adding a js function to ajax call the php curl to google maps.
- adding a js function to populate the fields with the response
- adding a php function to save the meta.

Mostly found by following this page :

https://www.taniarascia.com/wordpress-part-three-custom-fields-and-metaboxes/